# Unable to click checkbox inside <label for="chk"> tag using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, html-table, vue.js

I am trying to click checkbox within data cell td, but everytime I am getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

exception, 
issue is element is enabled but not visible.

Below is the Page source:

```
<table id='table1'>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input id='id1' class='class' type='checkbox'>
            <label for='chk1'>
            :: before
            </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input id='id2' class='class' type='checkbox'>
            <label for='chk2'>
            :: before
            </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input id='id3' class='class' type='checkbox'>
            <label for='chk3'>
            :: before
            </label>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but below code works and returns.

```
System.out.println("isDisplayed()"+ td_lblcollection.get(0).isDisplayed()); --> False
System.out.println("isEnabled()"+td_lblcollection.get(0).isEnabled()); --> True
System.out.println("isSelected()"+td_lblcollection.get(0).isSelected()); --> False
```

Manually checkbox is visible and able to select but IsDisplayed is false and element not visible exception is thrown.

Tried all below methods but everything fails. Locator is good.

Locator:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='table1']/tbody/tr")
List<WebElement> tblLookupSites;
```

Method1: Loop in Table

```
for (WebElement trElement : tblLookupSites) {
    List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
    List<WebElement> td_lblcollection =tdElement.findElements(By.xpath("label"));
    td_lblcollection.get(0).click();
}
}
```

Method2: Loop in Table

```
for (WebElement trElement : tblLookupSites) {
    List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
    List<WebElement> td_lblcollection =tdElement.findElements(By.xpath("input"));
    td_lblcollection.get(0).click();
}
}
```

Method3: Loop in Table

```
for (WebElement trElement : tblLookupSites) {
    List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
    List<WebElement> td_lblcollection =tdElement.findElements(By.id("id1"));
    td_lblcollection.get(0).click();
}
}
```

Please suggest how to click this checkbox.

UI is created using vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `JavascriptExecutor` interface to click non-visible element by inject some `javascript` like this way -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id1']"));
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Also try alternate way if it works- ( this is working in same kind of structure in my project)-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='chk1']")).click();
```

Comment: i have tried this before and tried again now, still didn't work.

Comment: Please try this, It may help - `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id1']"));
  JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: Awesome! Javascript worked, Thanks a lot Narendra _/|\_.

Comment: @Leo, nice to hear you. Please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following thing.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id1']")).click();

Comment: this will only work if you don't change a single thing in the document